# Как объединить все path в SVG?

Tags: svg

Как объединить все path и прочие элементы в SVG, чтобы при применении градиента, он применялся ко всему рисунку (файлу), а не к отдельным его частям и элементам? Если path или, например, circle, несколько, то градиент применяется к каждому из них по отдельности. Код для примера:

```html
<svg id="OBJECTS" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 301.82 44.23"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#4c3636}</style></defs><title></title><path class="cls-1" d="M150.91 9.09l-1.26-.82-9.09 13.85 10.35 15.75 10.34-15.75-10.34-15.76-1.26 1.91 1.26.82-1.26.82 8.01 12.21-6.75 10.29-6.76-10.29 8.01-12.21-1.25-.82-1.26.82 1.26-.82z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M150.91 16.81l-3.48 5.3 3.48 5.31 3.48-5.31-3.48-5.3z"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="133.09" cy="22.11" r="3.45"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="122.77" cy="22.11" r="2.13"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="114.32" cy="22.12" r="1.15"/><path class="cls-1" d="M108.16 20.61H17.25v3h90.91"/><path class="cls-1" d="M12.13 16.05l12.12 6.07-12.12 6.06L0 22.12l12.13-6.07zM92.97 2.18l-.41.29 3.09 4.33-2.68 3.76-2.68-3.76 3.09-4.33-.41-.29-.41.29.41-.29-.41-.29-3.5 4.91 3.91 5.49 3.91-5.49-3.91-5.48-.41.57.41.29zM33.76 3.64l-.41.29L35.4 6.8l-1.64 2.3-1.64-2.3 2.05-2.87-.41-.29-.41.29.41-.29-.41-.29-2.46 3.45 2.87 4.02 2.87-4.02-2.87-4.02-.41.57.41.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M233.65 97.91h-114a6.77 6.77 0 0 1-6.77-6.77 5.32 5.32 0 0 1 5.32-5.32 4.15 4.15 0 0 1 4.19 4.18 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-3.22 3.22 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-2.48-2.48 1.89 1.89 0 0 1 1.88-1.88v-1a2.88 2.88 0 0 0-2.88 2.88 3.48 3.48 0 0 0 3.48 3.48 4.22 4.22 0 0 0 4.22-4.22 5.15 5.15 0 0 0-5.15-5.15 6.32 6.32 0 0 0-6.32 6.32 7.77 7.77 0 0 0 7.77 7.77h114v-1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="19.47" cy="5.52" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M42.65 7.3h41.67v-1H42.65M92.97 42.05l.41.29 3.5-4.91-3.91-5.49-3.91 5.49 3.91 5.48.41-.57-.41-.29.41-.29-3.09-4.33 2.68-3.76 2.68 3.76-3.09 4.33.41.29.41-.29-.41.29zM33.76 40.59l.41.29 2.46-3.45-2.87-4.03-2.87 4.03 2.87 4.02.41-.57-.41-.29.41-.29-2.05-2.87 1.64-2.3 1.64 2.3-2.05 2.87.41.29.41-.29-.41.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M233.65 115h-114a7.77 7.77 0 0 0-7.77 7.77 6.32 6.32 0 0 0 6.32 6.32 5.15 5.15 0 0 0 5.15-5.15 4.22 4.22 0 0 0-4.22-4.22 3.48 3.48 0 0 0-3.48 3.48 2.88 2.88 0 0 0 2.88 2.88v-1a1.89 1.89 0 0 1-1.88-1.88 2.48 2.48 0 0 1 2.48-2.48 3.23 3.23 0 0 1 3.22 3.22 4.15 4.15 0 0 1-4.15 4.15 5.32 5.32 0 0 1-5.32-5.32 6.77 6.77 0 0 1 6.77-6.77h114v-1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="19.47" cy="38.71" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M42.65 37.93h41.67v-1H42.65"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="168.73" cy="22.11" r="3.45"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="179.04" cy="22.11" r="2.13"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="187.5" cy="22.12" r="1.15"/><path class="cls-1" d="M193.66 23.61h90.9v-3h-90.9"/><path class="cls-1" d="M289.69 16.05l-12.13 6.07 12.13 6.06 12.13-6.06-12.13-6.07zM208.85 2.18l-.41-.29-3.5 4.91 3.91 5.49 3.91-5.49-3.92-5.48-.4.57.41.29-.41.29 3.09 4.33-2.68 3.76-2.69-3.76 3.09-4.33-.4-.29-.41.29.41-.29zM268.06 3.64l-.41-.29-2.46 3.45 2.87 4.02 2.86-4.02-2.86-4.02-.41.57.41.29-.41.29 2.04 2.87-1.64 2.3-1.64-2.3 2.05-2.87-.4-.29-.41.29.41-.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M266.35 98.91h114a7.77 7.77 0 0 0 7.77-7.77 6.32 6.32 0 0 0-6.32-6.32 5.15 5.15 0 0 0-5.19 5.18 4.22 4.22 0 0 0 4.22 4.22 3.48 3.48 0 0 0 3.48-3.48 2.88 2.88 0 0 0-2.88-2.88v1a1.89 1.89 0 0 1 1.88 1.88 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-2.48 2.48 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-3.22-3.22 4.15 4.15 0 0 1 4.15-4.15 5.32 5.32 0 0 1 5.32 5.32 6.77 6.77 0 0 1-6.77 6.77h-114v1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="282.34" cy="5.52" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M259.17 6.3H217.5v1h41.67M208.85 42.05l.4-.29-3.09-4.33 2.69-3.76 2.68 3.76-3.09 4.33.41.29.4-.29-.4.29.4.29 3.51-4.91-3.91-5.49-3.91 5.49 3.91 5.48.4-.57-.4-.29zM268.06 40.59l.4-.29-2.05-2.87 1.64-2.3 1.64 2.3-2.04 2.87.41.29.4-.29-.4.29.4.29 2.46-3.45-2.86-4.03-2.87 4.03 2.87 4.02.4-.57-.4-.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M266.35 116h114a6.77 6.77 0 0 1 6.77 6.77 5.32 5.32 0 0 1-5.32 5.32 4.15 4.15 0 0 1-4.15-4.15 3.23 3.23 0 0 1 3.22-3.22 2.48 2.48 0 0 1 2.48 2.48 1.89 1.89 0 0 1-1.88 1.88v1a2.88 2.88 0 0 0 2.88-2.88 3.48 3.48 0 0 0-3.48-3.48 4.22 4.22 0 0 0-4.22 4.22 5.15 5.15 0 0 0 5.15 5.15 6.32 6.32 0 0 0 6.32-6.32 7.77 7.77 0 0 0-7.77-7.77h-114v1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="282.34" cy="38.71" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M259.17 36.93H217.5v1h41.67"/></svg>
```

Comment: Покажи наработки, так будет понятнее

Answer (score 3):

> Как объединить все path и прочие элементы в SVG, чтобы при применении
>   градиента, он применялся ко всему рисунку (файлу), а не к отдельным
>   его частям и элементам?

Чтобы градиент был применен ко всему SVG файлу, а точнее ко всем элементам, находящимся внутри него, нужно их все вместе обернуть в групповой тег и уже к нему применить градиент

```
 <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:dodgerblue;"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;"/>
    </linearGradient>

 </defs>

 <g fill="url(#grad1)">
 <path class="cls-1" ...  
</g>
```

```html
 <svg id="OBJECTS" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 301.82 44.23">
 <defs>
 
 
    <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:dodgerblue;"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;"/>
    </linearGradient>

 </defs>
 
 <title></title>
 
 <g fill="url(#grad1)">
 <path class="cls-1" d="M150.91 9.09l-1.26-.82-9.09 13.85 10.35 15.75 10.34-15.75-10.34-15.76-1.26 1.91 1.26.82-1.26.82 8.01 12.21-6.75 10.29-6.76-10.29 8.01-12.21-1.25-.82-1.26.82 1.26-.82z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M150.91 16.81l-3.48 5.3 3.48 5.31 3.48-5.31-3.48-5.3z"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="133.09" cy="22.11" r="3.45"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="122.77" cy="22.11" r="2.13"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="114.32" cy="22.12" r="1.15"/><path class="cls-1" d="M108.16 20.61H17.25v3h90.91"/><path class="cls-1" d="M12.13 16.05l12.12 6.07-12.12 6.06L0 22.12l12.13-6.07zM92.97 2.18l-.41.29 3.09 4.33-2.68 3.76-2.68-3.76 3.09-4.33-.41-.29-.41.29.41-.29-.41-.29-3.5 4.91 3.91 5.49 3.91-5.49-3.91-5.48-.41.57.41.29zM33.76 3.64l-.41.29L35.4 6.8l-1.64 2.3-1.64-2.3 2.05-2.87-.41-.29-.41.29.41-.29-.41-.29-2.46 3.45 2.87 4.02 2.87-4.02-2.87-4.02-.41.57.41.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M233.65 97.91h-114a6.77 6.77 0 0 1-6.77-6.77 5.32 5.32 0 0 1 5.32-5.32 4.15 4.15 0 0 1 4.19 4.18 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-3.22 3.22 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-2.48-2.48 1.89 1.89 0 0 1 1.88-1.88v-1a2.88 2.88 0 0 0-2.88 2.88 3.48 3.48 0 0 0 3.48 3.48 4.22 4.22 0 0 0 4.22-4.22 5.15 5.15 0 0 0-5.15-5.15 6.32 6.32 0 0 0-6.32 6.32 7.77 7.77 0 0 0 7.77 7.77h114v-1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="19.47" cy="5.52" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M42.65 7.3h41.67v-1H42.65M92.97 42.05l.41.29 3.5-4.91-3.91-5.49-3.91 5.49 3.91 5.48.41-.57-.41-.29.41-.29-3.09-4.33 2.68-3.76 2.68 3.76-3.09 4.33.41.29.41-.29-.41.29zM33.76 40.59l.41.29 2.46-3.45-2.87-4.03-2.87 4.03 2.87 4.02.41-.57-.41-.29.41-.29-2.05-2.87 1.64-2.3 1.64 2.3-2.05 2.87.41.29.41-.29-.41.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M233.65 115h-114a7.77 7.77 0 0 0-7.77 7.77 6.32 6.32 0 0 0 6.32 6.32 5.15 5.15 0 0 0 5.15-5.15 4.22 4.22 0 0 0-4.22-4.22 3.48 3.48 0 0 0-3.48 3.48 2.88 2.88 0 0 0 2.88 2.88v-1a1.89 1.89 0 0 1-1.88-1.88 2.48 2.48 0 0 1 2.48-2.48 3.23 3.23 0 0 1 3.22 3.22 4.15 4.15 0 0 1-4.15 4.15 5.32 5.32 0 0 1-5.32-5.32 6.77 6.77 0 0 1 6.77-6.77h114v-1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="19.47" cy="38.71" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M42.65 37.93h41.67v-1H42.65"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="168.73" cy="22.11" r="3.45"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="179.04" cy="22.11" r="2.13"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="187.5" cy="22.12" r="1.15"/><path class="cls-1" d="M193.66 23.61h90.9v-3h-90.9"/><path class="cls-1" d="M289.69 16.05l-12.13 6.07 12.13 6.06 12.13-6.06-12.13-6.07zM208.85 2.18l-.41-.29-3.5 4.91 3.91 5.49 3.91-5.49-3.92-5.48-.4.57.41.29-.41.29 3.09 4.33-2.68 3.76-2.69-3.76 3.09-4.33-.4-.29-.41.29.41-.29zM268.06 3.64l-.41-.29-2.46 3.45 2.87 4.02 2.86-4.02-2.86-4.02-.41.57.41.29-.41.29 2.04 2.87-1.64 2.3-1.64-2.3 2.05-2.87-.4-.29-.41.29.41-.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M266.35 98.91h114a7.77 7.77 0 0 0 7.77-7.77 6.32 6.32 0 0 0-6.32-6.32 5.15 5.15 0 0 0-5.19 5.18 4.22 4.22 0 0 0 4.22 4.22 3.48 3.48 0 0 0 3.48-3.48 2.88 2.88 0 0 0-2.88-2.88v1a1.89 1.89 0 0 1 1.88 1.88 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-2.48 2.48 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-3.22-3.22 4.15 4.15 0 0 1 4.15-4.15 5.32 5.32 0 0 1 5.32 5.32 6.77 6.77 0 0 1-6.77 6.77h-114v1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="282.34" cy="5.52" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M259.17 6.3H217.5v1h41.67M208.85 42.05l.4-.29-3.09-4.33 2.69-3.76 2.68 3.76-3.09 4.33.41.29.4-.29-.4.29.4.29 3.51-4.91-3.91-5.49-3.91 5.49 3.91 5.48.4-.57-.4-.29zM268.06 40.59l.4-.29-2.05-2.87 1.64-2.3 1.64 2.3-2.04 2.87.41.29.4-.29-.4.29.4.29 2.46-3.45-2.86-4.03-2.87 4.03 2.87 4.02.4-.57-.4-.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M266.35 116h114a6.77 6.77 0 0 1 6.77 6.77 5.32 5.32 0 0 1-5.32 5.32 4.15 4.15 0 0 1-4.15-4.15 3.23 3.23 0 0 1 3.22-3.22 2.48 2.48 0 0 1 2.48 2.48 1.89 1.89 0 0 1-1.88 1.88v1a2.88 2.88 0 0 0 2.88-2.88 3.48 3.48 0 0 0-3.48-3.48 4.22 4.22 0 0 0-4.22 4.22 5.15 5.15 0 0 0 5.15 5.15 6.32 6.32 0 0 0 6.32-6.32 7.77 7.77 0 0 0-7.77-7.77h-114v1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="282.34" cy="38.71" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M259.17 36.93H217.5v1h41.67"/>
 </g>
 
 </svg>
```

Comment: @Plutooo Если ответ вам был полезен, - не забудьте поставить плюс и галочку

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то можно ничего объединять, можно использовать `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` для градиента.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
Array(33).fill(0).map(() => {
  svg.innerHTML = svg.innerHTML + `
      <circle fill="url(#gradient)" r="10" 
              cx="${Math.random()*600}" 
              cy="${Math.random()*150}">
      </circle>
  `;
})
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 100" width="600" height="150">

<defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0);"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>

</svg>
```

Но к сожалению Ваша картинка использует transform, который ломает логику закраски градиентом...

```css
path, circle {
  fill:url(#gradient)
}
```

```html
<svg id="OBJECTS" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 301.82 44.23">

<defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0);"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>

<title></title><path class="cls-1" d="M150.91 9.09l-1.26-.82-9.09 13.85 10.35 15.75 10.34-15.75-10.34-15.76-1.26 1.91 1.26.82-1.26.82 8.01 12.21-6.75 10.29-6.76-10.29 8.01-12.21-1.25-.82-1.26.82 1.26-.82z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M150.91 16.81l-3.48 5.3 3.48 5.31 3.48-5.31-3.48-5.3z"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="133.09" cy="22.11" r="3.45"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="122.77" cy="22.11" r="2.13"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="114.32" cy="22.12" r="1.15"/><path class="cls-1" d="M108.16 20.61H17.25v3h90.91"/><path class="cls-1" d="M12.13 16.05l12.12 6.07-12.12 6.06L0 22.12l12.13-6.07zM92.97 2.18l-.41.29 3.09 4.33-2.68 3.76-2.68-3.76 3.09-4.33-.41-.29-.41.29.41-.29-.41-.29-3.5 4.91 3.91 5.49 3.91-5.49-3.91-5.48-.41.57.41.29zM33.76 3.64l-.41.29L35.4 6.8l-1.64 2.3-1.64-2.3 2.05-2.87-.41-.29-.41.29.41-.29-.41-.29-2.46 3.45 2.87 4.02 2.87-4.02-2.87-4.02-.41.57.41.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M233.65 97.91h-114a6.77 6.77 0 0 1-6.77-6.77 5.32 5.32 0 0 1 5.32-5.32 4.15 4.15 0 0 1 4.19 4.18 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-3.22 3.22 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-2.48-2.48 1.89 1.89 0 0 1 1.88-1.88v-1a2.88 2.88 0 0 0-2.88 2.88 3.48 3.48 0 0 0 3.48 3.48 4.22 4.22 0 0 0 4.22-4.22 5.15 5.15 0 0 0-5.15-5.15 6.32 6.32 0 0 0-6.32 6.32 7.77 7.77 0 0 0 7.77 7.77h114v-1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="19.47" cy="5.52" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M42.65 7.3h41.67v-1H42.65M92.97 42.05l.41.29 3.5-4.91-3.91-5.49-3.91 5.49 3.91 5.48.41-.57-.41-.29.41-.29-3.09-4.33 2.68-3.76 2.68 3.76-3.09 4.33.41.29.41-.29-.41.29zM33.76 40.59l.41.29 2.46-3.45-2.87-4.03-2.87 4.03 2.87 4.02.41-.57-.41-.29.41-.29-2.05-2.87 1.64-2.3 1.64 2.3-2.05 2.87.41.29.41-.29-.41.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M233.65 115h-114a7.77 7.77 0 0 0-7.77 7.77 6.32 6.32 0 0 0 6.32 6.32 5.15 5.15 0 0 0 5.15-5.15 4.22 4.22 0 0 0-4.22-4.22 3.48 3.48 0 0 0-3.48 3.48 2.88 2.88 0 0 0 2.88 2.88v-1a1.89 1.89 0 0 1-1.88-1.88 2.48 2.48 0 0 1 2.48-2.48 3.23 3.23 0 0 1 3.22 3.22 4.15 4.15 0 0 1-4.15 4.15 5.32 5.32 0 0 1-5.32-5.32 6.77 6.77 0 0 1 6.77-6.77h114v-1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="19.47" cy="38.71" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M42.65 37.93h41.67v-1H42.65"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="168.73" cy="22.11" r="3.45"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="179.04" cy="22.11" r="2.13"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="187.5" cy="22.12" r="1.15"/><path class="cls-1" d="M193.66 23.61h90.9v-3h-90.9"/><path class="cls-1" d="M289.69 16.05l-12.13 6.07 12.13 6.06 12.13-6.06-12.13-6.07zM208.85 2.18l-.41-.29-3.5 4.91 3.91 5.49 3.91-5.49-3.92-5.48-.4.57.41.29-.41.29 3.09 4.33-2.68 3.76-2.69-3.76 3.09-4.33-.4-.29-.41.29.41-.29zM268.06 3.64l-.41-.29-2.46 3.45 2.87 4.02 2.86-4.02-2.86-4.02-.41.57.41.29-.41.29 2.04 2.87-1.64 2.3-1.64-2.3 2.05-2.87-.4-.29-.41.29.41-.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M266.35 98.91h114a7.77 7.77 0 0 0 7.77-7.77 6.32 6.32 0 0 0-6.32-6.32 5.15 5.15 0 0 0-5.19 5.18 4.22 4.22 0 0 0 4.22 4.22 3.48 3.48 0 0 0 3.48-3.48 2.88 2.88 0 0 0-2.88-2.88v1a1.89 1.89 0 0 1 1.88 1.88 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-2.48 2.48 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-3.22-3.22 4.15 4.15 0 0 1 4.15-4.15 5.32 5.32 0 0 1 5.32 5.32 6.77 6.77 0 0 1-6.77 6.77h-114v1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="282.34" cy="5.52" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M259.17 6.3H217.5v1h41.67M208.85 42.05l.4-.29-3.09-4.33 2.69-3.76 2.68 3.76-3.09 4.33.41.29.4-.29-.4.29.4.29 3.51-4.91-3.91-5.49-3.91 5.49 3.91 5.48.4-.57-.4-.29zM268.06 40.59l.4-.29-2.05-2.87 1.64-2.3 1.64 2.3-2.04 2.87.41.29.4-.29-.4.29.4.29 2.46-3.45-2.86-4.03-2.87 4.03 2.87 4.02.4-.57-.4-.29z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M266.35 116h114a6.77 6.77 0 0 1 6.77 6.77 5.32 5.32 0 0 1-5.32 5.32 4.15 4.15 0 0 1-4.15-4.15 3.23 3.23 0 0 1 3.22-3.22 2.48 2.48 0 0 1 2.48 2.48 1.89 1.89 0 0 1-1.88 1.88v1a2.88 2.88 0 0 0 2.88-2.88 3.48 3.48 0 0 0-3.48-3.48 4.22 4.22 0 0 0-4.22 4.22 5.15 5.15 0 0 0 5.15 5.15 6.32 6.32 0 0 0 6.32-6.32 7.77 7.77 0 0 0-7.77-7.77h-114v1z" transform="translate(-99.09 -84.83)"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="282.34" cy="38.71" r="2.6"/><path class="cls-1" d="M259.17 36.93H217.5v1h41.67"/></svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Скорее всего, делаю что-то не то, наверное, но градиент остаётся прежним, на каждый элемент, а не вся картинка равномерно.